# Use subdomain for S3 assets in multi-site Craft installation

Tags: templating, assets, s3

I have found the section in settings where I can set the URL Prefix for an asset source using a CNAME and pointing to the relative S3 bucket where the file actually lives but I am using a multi site environment so I need the value of the URL Prefix to be dynamic.

I have tried setting it to `assets.{{ craft()->request->getServerName() }}`, also have tried `assets.{% craft()->request->getServerName() %}`but that is what's getting spit out on the page (asset url as rendered on page looks like `assets.{% craft()->request->getServerName() %}images/home-banner.jpg`.

How can I make Craft parse this field's dynamic value? The statement isn't parsed as it would be if it was in a Twig template.

Comment: I'm not sure about your complete setup and requirements, but maybe you could create a separate asset source for each prefix / subdomain?

Answer (score 1):

Your example of setting the S3 "URL Prefix" setting to something dynamic won't work because there are only a few settings in the Control Panel that Craft parses for dynamic Twig content and that isn't one of them.  i.e. in an Asset Field's [Upload Location](https://craftcms.com/docs/assets-fields#dynamic-subfolder-paths), Section Title/URL Formats, etc.

Honestly, I don't think there currently is a way to do that in Craft 2.

This should be possible in the upcoming [Craft 3](https://craftcms.com/3) by [overriding the setting](https://github.com/craftcms/docs/blob/master/en/configuration.md#overriding-volume-settings) in `config/volumes.php` and doing your dynamic logic from PHP.